# How can I fetch image format from a URL in Java?

Tags: java, image, image-processing, bufferedimage, javax.imageio

I have an image that I fetch from a url that has no extension(jpg, gif,png, etc).

I have no problem downloading the image.

```
BufferedImage image = null;
URL url = new URL(link);
image = ImageIO.read(url);
```

However, I wanted to know the extension of the file before saving to disk. I tried the following and **`ImageIO.createImageInputStream(image);`** is always returning null.

```
ImageInputStream iis = ImageIO.createImageInputStream(image);
//where image is BufferImage but it is always returning null.

while (imageReaders.hasNext()) {
    ImageReader reader = imageReaders.next();
    System.out.printf("formatName: %s%n", reader.getFormatName());

    return ImageFormatTypes.valueOf(reader.getFormatName());
}
```

Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: It's `ImageIO.createImageInputStream(url)` (i.e. not `image`). Don't read the image, you don't need to, if you only want to save to disk.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Once you create a java.awt.Image, there is no format.  It's not a PNG, it's not a JPEG, it's just a Java Image.  So you cannot get the image format from your Image object.

You need to get it from the URL.  The most reliable way is to check the URL's content type, then get the extension from the ImageIO provider:

```
URL url = new URL(link);
URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
String contentType = conn.getContentType();

String suffix = null;
Iterator<ImageReader> readers =
    ImageIO.getImageReadersByMIMEType(contentType);
while (suffix == null && readers.hasNext()) {
    ImageReaderSpi provider = readers.next().getOriginatingProvider();
    if (provider != null) {
        String[] suffixes = provider.getFileSuffixes();
        if (suffixes != null) {
            suffix = suffixes[0];
        }
    }
}
```

You can also save the URL to a temporary file, so you can use Files.probeContentType on it:

```
URL url = new URL(link);
Path imageFile = Files.createTempFile("image", null);
try (InputStream stream = url.openStream()) {
    Files.copy(stream, imageFile, StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
}

image = ImageIO.read(imageFile.toFile());
String contentType = Files.probeContentType(imageFile);
Files.delete(imageFile);
```

But you'll still need ImageIO providers to get an extension from a MIME type.

Comment: Thank you so much @VGR. This is what I was looking for. One quick question though: String contentType = conn.getContentType(); This is already giving me image/png. Isn't it enough to stop at this stage?

Comment: No.  The subtype (the part after the `/`) is not guaranteed to be the same as the extension.  Consider "image/jpeg" and "image/svg+xml".

Comment: Also, some servers are lying about content types (i.e. are misconfigured, or relies on file extension which may be incorrect). So you can't blindly trust the content type. Looking at the actual payload, like `Files.probeContentType(..)` does is safer.

Answer (score 3):

In Java 7+ you can now just use [Files.probeContentType(path)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#probeContentType%28java.nio.file.Path%29).

```
----------
public static String probeContentType(Path path)
                               throws IOException
```

> Probes the content type of a file.
>
> This method uses the installed FileTypeDetector implementations to
>   probe the given file to determine its content type. Each file type
>   detector's probeContentType is invoked, in turn, to probe the file
>   type. If the file is recognized then the content type is returned. If
>   the file is not recognized by any of the installed file type detectors
>   then a system-default file type detector is invoked to guess the
>   content type.
>
> A given invocation of the Java virtual machine maintains a system-wide
>   list of file type detectors. Installed file type detectors are loaded
>   using the service-provider loading facility defined by the
>   ServiceLoader class. Installed file type detectors are loaded using
>   the system class loader. If the system class loader cannot be found
>   then the extension class loader is used; If the extension class loader
>   cannot be found then the bootstrap class loader is used. File type
>   detectors are typically installed by placing them in a JAR file on the
>   application class path or in the extension directory, the JAR file
>   contains a provider-configuration file named
>   java.nio.file.spi.FileTypeDetector in the resource directory
>   META-INF/services, and the file lists one or more fully-qualified
>   names of concrete subclass of FileTypeDetector that have a zero
>   argument constructor. If the process of locating or instantiating the
>   installed file type detectors fails then an unspecified error is
>   thrown. The ordering that installed providers are located is
>   implementation specific.
>
> The return value of this method is the string form of the value of a
>   Multipurpose Internet Mail Extension (MIME) content type as defined by
>   RFC 2045: Multipurpose Internet Mail Extensions (MIME) Part One:
>   Format of Internet Message Bodies. The string is guaranteed to be
>   parsable according to the grammar in the RFC.

Comment: Thank you for the answer and I guess understood it. However I was trying to get the Path and used the following code.  Path path=Paths.get(url.toURI()); However, it is throwing FileSystemNotFoundException : Provider 'http' not installed. Am I right getting the Path object ?

Comment: Thanks again. What library are you using for Path and Paths? I don't seem to see Paths.getPath method. Only Paths.get() method. I see package java.nio.file for both classes. I am using JDK 1.8

Comment: I know you mentioned Java 7 but I thought it is also applicable for Java 8.

Comment: Paths.getPath will only work for 'file:' URIs (and URIs based on filesystems like the zip file system).

Comment: I guess I cannot understood your question @WowBow, what are you trying to achieve ?

Comment: There is no method Paths.getPath. There are two methods of Paths.get with different parameter.

Comment: "The `getPath` method converts a system dependent path string, returning a Path object that may be used to locate and access a file" https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/FileSystem.html

Comment: @VGR I am trying to using the Path class as I have to pass one of its instances to probeContentType. But how can I convert the image URL I have (for e.g www.stackoverflow.com/3455jju4gs9 ) to a Path object. The image is coming from a URL not saved in local disk and I was going to use probeContentType(path) to find the type of the image before saving it locally. Does it makes sense?

Comment: @PedroLobito What I am trying to achieve is download an image from a URL but before I save it locally I have to find its format type(jpg,png, etc). Your answer makes sense but I couldn't find a way to construct a Path object from the URL. And There is no such method Paths.getPath .

Comment: I'm sorry, but your question doesn't make sense to me. Why can you just find the extension on the url ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76730/discussion-between-wowbow-and-pedro-lobito).

Comment: If the url doesn't have extension just download the file and find the image type with `probeContentType(path)`.  I guess your complicating something easy.

Comment: The URL has no extension. For e.g the URL might look like something like this www.stackoverflow.com/3455jju4gs9 . It is an image but it doesn't have *.jpg or *.png url.

Comment: I am not complicating anything. In order to download the file and save to disk I have to mention the file type. And since the URL has no extension there was no way I can tell what its type is so I have to figure out the file type(format) before downloading. I am using ImageIO.write and you can see that it looks for formatName. ImageIO.write(RenderedImage im,
                                String formatName,
                                File output )

Comment: "__In order to download the file and save to disk I have to mention the file type__" this assumption is wrong, and yes, you're complicating. Save the file to a temp path and use `Files.probeContentType(path).` to check the image format, that all you need.

Comment: @PedroLobito Thank you for the help. VGR's first solution is what I was looking for. Anyhow, I appreciate your help.